# Como realizar insert ou update de um objeto JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Objeto JSON `$postdata`:

```
{
    "0": {
        "codigo": "1",
        "descricao": "Bobina",
        "preco": "10.0000"
    },
    "1": {
        "codigo": "2",
        "descricao": "Capa",
        "preco": "20.0000"
    }
}
```

Utilizando MySQL, como realizar `insert` se não existir ou `update` caso possua o respectivo registro no BD?

**Edição**:

O atributo [código, descrição e preço] de cada item ["0", "1"] será inserido no banco de dados em sua respectiva coluna.

**Edição II**:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$request = json_decode($postdata); 
$id = $request->id; ...
```

Comment: Calma ai, sua coluna é do tipo json? ou vc quer jogar as informações do json para o banco (separando os valores nas respectivas colunas)?

Comment: Olá @rray, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Na parte do preco 10 e 20 qual é o valor real dali é 20 reais e 10 reais?

Comment: Sim, @VirgilioNovic são valores fictícios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma, com Orientação a Objeto:

Classe `database`

```
<?php

class database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($dsn='mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=new_schema',
                                $user='root',
                                $pass='senha')
    {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }
}
```

Classe `data`

```
<?php

class data
{
    private $codigo;
    private $descricao;
    private $preco;

    public function __construct($codigo = 0, $descricao = '', $preco = 0)
    {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
        $this->descricao = $descricao;
        $this->preco = $preco;
    }

    public function getCodigo()
    {
        return $this->codigo;
    }
    public function setCodigo($codigo)
    {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getDescricao()
    {
        return $this->descricao;
    }
    public function setDescricao($descricao)
    {
        $this->descricao = $descricao;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPreco()
    {
        return $this->preco;
    }
    public function setPreco($preco)
    {
        $this->preco = $preco;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Classe `daoData`

```
<?php

class daoData
{
    private $database;
    public function __construct(database $database)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function insert(data $data)
    {
        $stmt = $this->database
            ->prepare('INSERT INTO tb_data(codigo, descricao, preco) VALUES(?,?,?)');

        $stmt->bindValue(1, $data->getCodigo());
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $data->getDescricao());
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $data->getPreco());

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        return $result;
    }
    public function update(data $data)
    {
        $stmt = $this->database
            ->prepare('UPDATE tb_data SET descricao=?, preco=? WHERE codigo=?');

        $stmt->bindValue(1, $data->getDescricao());
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $data->getPreco());
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $data->getCodigo());

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        return $result;
    }

    public function insertOrUpdate(data $data)
    {
        $stmt = $this->database->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_data WHERE codigo=?');
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $data->getCodigo());
        if ($stmt->execute())
        {
            $result = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
            $stmt->closeCursor();
            return $result == 0 ?
                $this->insert($data) :
                $this->update($data);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`index.php`

```
<?php

require 'database.php';
require 'data.php';
require 'daodata.php';

$json = '{
    "0": {
        "codigo": "1",
        "descricao": "Bobina",
        "preco": "10.0000"
    },
    "1": {
        "codigo": "2",
        "descricao": "Capa",
        "preco": "20.0000"
    }
}';

$dataJson = json_decode($json, true);    

$database = new database();

$dao = new daoData($database);

foreach($dataJson as $key => $item)
{
    $data = new data($item['codigo'],
        $item['descricao'],
        $item['preco']);
    $dao->insertOrUpdate($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tera que converter o JSON para um objeto PHP ou um array utilizando o `json_encode()` - http://php.net/json_encode

Depois verificar no banco se os ids existem, caso ja existam no banco faça um `UPDATE`, senão um `INSERT`.

Comment: Caso queira uma resposta mais especifica, avance nesses passos e a cada dificuldade faça uma pergunta nova com um problema especifico, perguntas assim abertas são complicadas de responder.

Comment: Marcos, já tenho o seguinte: `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$id = $request->id; ...`

Comment: Ótimo, pra facilitar, edita a sua pergunta e coloca o código que você ja tem lá.